# Can I find whether a Cell in Excel is referenced in a formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched alot of sites on the internet, and I'm guessing I haven't found an answer because it is not possible, to try to understand the following:

I would like to understand if a Cell containing a value (say 10) plays into / forms part of a formula further into the document. I KNOW that the cell I have is NOT a formula cell, it is a single entry, however, I am trying to understand if this cell forms part of a formula. The need for this is there are ALOT of formulas and ALOT of data, and I am trying to see which data is relvant and which data is not.

Hope somone can help?

Kind regards

Paul

Comment: It is possible to do this in VBA. It would imply looping through all the cells, evaluating if it's a formula, and if so, identify the addresses found in the formula. For large files, though, I'd suspect this to be highly time-consuming as it has exponential complexity...

Comment: If any of your formulas use INDIRECT() it's going to be a lot more difficult...

Comment: Also need to account for named ranges.

Comment: See discussion here: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/printthread.php?t=126236

Answer (score 2):

Manually you can use "Trace Dependents" on the 'Formula Auditing' menu under "Formulas" tool tab.

Using VBA you can check the number of dependents like this:

```
Range("A1").Dependents.Count
```

---

If you want a list of cell addresses that cell A1 is used in you can do this:

```
MsgBox (Range("A1").Dependents.Address)
```

I have A1 used in two other cells so my result looks like this:

[image]

---

Full code with error checking:

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Range("A1").Dependents Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("No dependents found")
    Else
        MsgBox (Range("A1").Dependents.Address)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Dependents` property of a `Range` object gives you the dependent cells of your formula. Be careful you will get an error if there are no dependent cells

```
Function hasDependents(r As Range) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo err
    hasDenpedents = r.Dependents
    Exit Function
err:
    hasDependents = False
End Function
```

And then

```
if hasDependents([A1]) then
    '...
```